# Handling POST - BadRequest - GET cycle

Tags: playframework, securesocial

I have a form which sends a POST request to controller (post url = myForm/save ), now if validation fails I send a badRequest() from controller to client.

The pages renders correctly showing the validation error and filled form. (However URL remains myForm/save in address bar, as expected).

Now if I wait on this page and session expire, and then resubmit form Secure Social takes me to the Login page. After successful login, Secure social will remember the last URL (myForm/save) and try a GET request to render the page. Here comes the problem because last url was a POST request but to render page Secure Social send a GET request to controller.

And this causes a 'Action Not Found'. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to duplicate the path in your routes to add a GET request ?

```
POST  /myForm/save       com.controllers.Application.index()
GET   /myForm/save       com.controllers.Application.index()
```

Comment: Using this will avoid the Action not found error, but since it is a Get request all the form data will be lost. Also, it seems more like a back up solution. thanks anywayz.

Comment: I don't think it's the best thing to try an other post request after a session expire. You should redirect the user to a new form after login. Maybe you can prefill the form if you save the data with an ajax call before session expire.